# std::thread not getting scheduled after sometime c++11 (Windows Sever)

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I noticed in my application, that sometimes some of the threads are not at all getting scheduled after sometime (sometimes it runs for 10 minutes and then it is not at getting scheduled. BTW this application is on Windows Server 2008 VM). Following is the code snippet for the same.

Generic routine to create a detachable thread.

```
auto executeOnNewThread(std::function<void()> f)->void
{
    try {
      std::thread t([=]() { f();  });
      t.detach();
    } catch (...) {
        LOG_ERROR(L"Failed to create new thread");
    }
}
```

Infinte loop routine to execute

```
auto executeTask() const->void 
{
    auto count = 0;
    for (;;) {
       Sleep(2000);

       LOG_ON_DEMAND(L"Monitor thread running...");
       // Routine to checkAndNotifyTaskAvailable;
       LOG_ON_DEMAND(L"End 2 Monitor thread running...");
       // monitorTasks;
       LOG_ON_DEMAND(L"End 3 Monitor thread running...");
   }
}
```

Invoking the function to execute on new thread.

```
executeOnNewThread([=]() { executeTask();  });
```

I can see all the logs for sometime and afterwards no logs at all. Just to confirm, I cross checked with the procexp.exe and there also, this corresponding thread is not at all getting scheduled at all (Infact few more threads like this are not getting scheduled). Following is the stack trace for the same (when it was not scheduled).

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x2246
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x135e
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xdd9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x373
ntoskrnl.exe!KeStallWhileFrozen+0x1977
ntoskrnl.exe!PoStartNextPowerIrp+0x109d
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x152f
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xdd9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x373
ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xb2
ntoskrnl.exe!_setjmpex+0x34a3
wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x598
wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x3e4
wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x23a
wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x172
ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x12b
ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc
MSVCR120.dll!??0_Interruption_exception@details@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ+0x41e
MSVCR120.dll!?unlock@critical_section@Concurrency@@QAEXXZ+0xde
MSVCR120.dll!?lock@critical_section@Concurrency@@QAEXXZ+0x25
.... // My Application code.
MSVCR120.dll!__get_tlsindex+0x6f
MSVCR120.dll!__get_tlsindex+0x53
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x8f
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x5a
```

Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you used a debugger?  You have some code commented out, but if something there is blocked (waiting on a mutex, condition variable, etc.) the threads will keep sleeping.

Comment: The stack trace is very low quality, debug symbols are required.  It doesn't look healthy, make a minidump and investigate with windbg.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Actually I made a silly mistake during the logging. Instead of logging to the file by each thread, I pushed them to a Q, so that a periodic worker thread will put  these messages to the log file. Since there are so many threads that are pushing the messages to the Q, so this thread was not getting chance to execute. After modifying the code, it worked as expected.